# How i can change _type param in during import data into elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, pgsync

I getting this

[image]

while import with schema.json description from postgres via pgsync

[image]

I want to override the value from _type: _doc to something else. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, `_type` is a metadata field that was used until version 6.X to have different document types in the same index, this is not possible anymore.

In version 6.X you could have indices with a custom value for `_type`, but just one per index, on version 7.X the value for the `_type` field is `_doc`, and on the upcoming version 8.X this field and its related API won't exist anymore.

You can however create a new field named `type` and use any value you want, how you will do this depends on how you are ingesting your data.

For more information about the removal of types in elasticsearch you can check this official [blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/moving-from-types-to-typeless-apis-in-elasticsearch-7-0) and this part of the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#removal-of-types).

Comment: Thanks. How i can to create this field in my case? You can update your answer with an example of a **scheme.json** chunk?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I do not use pgsync and have no knowledge about how it works, you could check on their [github](https://github.com/toluaina/pgsync) or wait to see if someone who uses this tool can give some other input.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the PGSync plugin to modify the metadata. This is described here https://pgsync.com/tutorial/plugins/